# Complete Linearly ordered Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is there any Complete metric space other than $R$ or subsets of $R$ which is linearly ordered ?

Comment: you need to state some relations between order and metric otherwise you can put any linear order

Comment: I think the question is to consider an order topology for some linear order $( X,< )$ that is homeomorphic to a complete metric space.  Does this have to be homeomorphic to some subset of $\mathbb R$ under the standard topology?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Let $X=\kappa\times\Bbb Z$, where $\kappa$ is any cardinal, and let $\preceq$ be the lexicographic order on $X$. The order topology on $X$ induced by $\preceq$ is discrete, so $X$ is completely metrizable *via* the metric

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x\ne y\\0,&\text{if }x=y\;:\end{cases}$$

the Cauchy sequences are precisely the sequences that are eventually constant. Since we can take $\kappa>2^\omega$, the result follows.

Comment: Actually, on a related note, would a Suslin line, if it exists, be another counterexample, or is it homeomorphic to some subset of the real line?

Comment: @Andrew: No, because it’s not metrizable. (Sorry about the silly first version of this comment.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think of that.